# How does squeezed multimode light, where the modes are entangled, behave in a beamsplitter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, interference, wigner-transform, squeezed-states

I understand how to work with and describe squeezed single modes going through a beamsplitter, and can conceptually talk about what's happening. If I now take a source of squeezed light that has multiple modes, **which are entangled with each other** (bipartite/tripartite/etc states), how does this interfere when:

1. I send it through a beamsplitter in one port, and a vacuum state in the other port?
2. I send two of these multimode sources through a beamsplitter, one through each port?

I'm looking for insight both from a "write out the maths" point of view and a conceptual one :)

Comment: See [Mixing nonclassical pure states in a linear-optical network almost always generates modal entanglement](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.88.044301) - the only pure states that do not become entangled are displaced squeezed states where each mode has the same amount of squeezing and the phases are arranged in a particular way

Comment: For one port being vacuum, all you need for entanglement generation is Glauber-Sudarshan nonclassicality in the input port [Theorem for the beam-splitter entangler](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.66.024303)

Comment: For both ports being nonvacuum, there are Glauber-Sudarshan nonclassical mixed states that still remain separable, so it is not so simple in general (https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/aad7c6)